# Extend PDO prepare method to replace query prefix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have a code below and try to change this line:

```
$sth    = $db->prepare(Utils::prepareSQLPrefix($sql, Config::get('DB_PREFIX')));
```

To extend some kind $db->prepare function in my DatabaseFactory class (To replace query prefix).

```
$db         = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$sql        = ' SELECT 
                    `id`, `manifest`
                FROM 
                    `#__extensions`
                WHERE 
                    `name` = :name
                LIMIT 1';

        $sth    = $db->prepare(Utils::prepareSQLPrefix($sql, Config::get('DB_PREFIX')));
        $sth->execute(array('name' =>$extension->component_name));
        $result = $sth->fetch();
```

My DatabaseFactory class:

```
class DatabaseFactory {
    private static $factory;
    private $database;

    public static function getFactory()
    {
        if (!self::$factory) {
            self::$factory = new DatabaseFactory();
        }
        return self::$factory;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        if (!$this->database) {
            $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->database = new PDO(
                    Config::get('DB_TYPE') . ':host=' . Config::get('DB_HOST') . ';dbname=' .
                    Config::get('DB_NAME') . ';port=' . Config::get('DB_PORT') . ';charset=' . Config::get('DB_CHARSET'),
                    Config::get('DB_USER'), Config::get('DB_PASS'), $options
            );

        }

        return $this->database;
    }
}
```

My Utils class:

```
class Utils { 
    public static function prepareSQLPrefix($sql, $prefix) {
        return str_replace('#__', $prefix, $sql);   
    }
}
```

How can I doing this? Thanks!

Comment: your code seems to be valid. what is the problem or issue do you have?

Comment: I would like to move prepareSQLPrefix to DatabaseFactory class

Comment: you should use _contruct on DatabaseFactory class and then use parent::construct on Utils. or use protected and extend DatabaseFactory to an child class

Comment: Here `$sth->execute(array('name' =>$extension->component_name));` you should use `:name` instead of `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should create new class which extends `PDO` and redefine `prepare` function :

```
class myPDO extends PDO {

    public function prepare ($sql, $options = NULL) {
        $sql = Utils::prepareSQLPrefix($sql, Config::get('DB_PREFIX'));
        return parent::prepare($sql, $options);
    }

}
```

Then you change your factory `getConnection` to:

```
 public function getConnection() {
    if (!$this->database) {
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->database = new myPDO(
                Config::get('DB_TYPE') . ':host=' . Config::get('DB_HOST') . ';dbname=' .
                Config::get('DB_NAME') . ';port=' . Config::get('DB_PORT') . ';charset=' . Config::get('DB_CHARSET'),
                Config::get('DB_USER'), Config::get('DB_PASS'), $options
        );

    }

    return $this->database;
}
```

and then instead of :

```
$sth    = $db->prepare(Utils::prepareSQLPrefix($sql, Config::get('DB_PREFIX')));
```

you can just:

```
$sth    = $db->prepare($sql);
```

getting same expected result

Comment: Thank you! I have update my code but getting an error: Strict standards: Declaration of DB::prepare() should be compatible with PDO::prepare($statement, $options = NULL) in ...\core\DB.php on line 52

Comment: because you did it your way not mine. Do what I said, but not what you think you understood. class `myPDO` should be separated class with one redefined method. But you did it differently - why? you do `$this->database = new DB(` so that seems as recursive call inside `DB` class why do you do that?

Comment: @user889349  by the way I've read your error posted so add `, $options = NULL` to `prepare` function redefined

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Can you update your answer with full class and how can I use it example? Thank you.

Comment: @user889349 I already updated my answer. just take your original code as a base and follow my answer.

Comment: I'm using this: $db = DB::getConnection(); and getting: Using $this when not in object context in ...\core\DB.php on line 40

Comment: Could you just follow the answer? let do it step by step? tell me when you rollback to your original code and create `myPDO`  class as I posted please.

Comment: @user889349 listen... you don't need to touch your original code. your original `class DatabaseFactory {` was fine. I never asked to change the name of the class. remove both **update** from your question. roll back to your original code and follow the answer!

Comment: If your PHP version is >= 5.10, you should change `public function prepare ($sql, $options = NULL)` for `public function prepare ($sql, $options = array())`